# Java Swing - inform GUI about changes to the model

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablemodel

I have a column in JTable that binds to the underlying boolean property on a list of business objects. I also have a combobox, which should select which items should be selected. I basically added the following code as a handler to the combobox:

```
            macroCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
                    Predicate filter = (Predicate) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    for(SelectableKey key : tableEntries){
                        key.setSelected(filter.evaluate(key));
                    }
                }
            });
```

I also have a few other controls I want to change based on the value. At the moment, only a few cells in the table change their state to be selected/deselected. Only when I click on the row, or select multiple rows, the UI updates itself. Is there a call from the handler I need to make to tell GUI to redraw itself? ALos, if I modify other controls than JTable, how would I tell them to change their state?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you update a value in your `TableModel`, the model should fire a corresponding `TableModelEvent` (type: `UPDATE`).

If your `TableModel` for example extends from `AbstractTableModel`, you can call the [`fireTableRowsUpdated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsUpdated%28int,%20int%29) method after you have made the changes.

Another approach is a `TableModel` which knows when it gets updated (for example by adding listeners to the objects it contains). This allows other code to simply update the objects contained in the `TableModel`, without having knowledge of the `TableModel`. The `TableModel` itself will then fire the event when it detects changes made to the objects it contains.

I prefer the second approach, as this avoids that I have to pass that `TableModel` around to all my other classes.

Consult the [table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

Comment: So in your second approach, you would add the TableModel as a listener to each business objects that underpin it, and whenever each of them change, you raise event that is picked by the model?

Comment: @Bober02 The table model or a listener which knows about the tablemodel (e.g. anonymous class in the tablemodel)